# Bind live form with live grid on Wavemaker studio desktop 7.5

Tags: forms, grid, wavemaker

I've been trying to perform this for a few days and I still can't accomplish it. I search a lot with no results.

On a Wavemaker studio destop project page I have: 
- A **grid** of "Clients" (bind to a database clients table) 
- A **live form** of new vehicles (bind to a database vehicles table)

**The form has a field called "Client". I want this field to be automatically filled up with the Client selected on the grid above.**

The grid works fine displaying the Clients info.

The form works fine if I choose a combo list of clients to show up on the field. But I just cant bind the field with the selected item on the clients grid.

Just to clarify, on the database, Client is a foreign key for Vehicles table.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly this is beacause a bug :-(

Here is the answer / override alternative http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/13533